# "Moral" difference between Poincare and Sobolev inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I wonder what are the "moral" differences between Poincare and Sobolev inequalities.
Let me state them (hopefully without errors) using Wikipedia as source:

**Poincare inequalities**
Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb R^n$ bounded in at least one direction, then there exists some $C = C(p, \Omega)$ such that for all $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ ($1\leq p < \infty$)
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C \Vert \nabla u \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)}
$$
We can also change the condition of $u$ belonging in $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ by $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $\int_\Omega u dx = 0$ (only for bounded $\Omega$). This is called Poincare-Wirtinger.

**Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality**
Assume $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ (in Wikipedia they say $u\in C^1(\mathbb R^n)$ with compact support but by density I think it doesn't matter, correct me if I'm wrong please).
Then for $p \in [1,n)$, there exists some $C=C(p)>0$ such that
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{p^*} \leq C \Vert \nabla u \Vert_{p}
$$
where $p^*$ is some real number larger than $p$ and depending on $n$ and $p$.

I can see that Poincare inequalities are intimately related to domains, whereas GNS isn't. But at first glance, GNS is stronger because if we assume $\Omega$ bounded then $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \subset W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ (by extending $u$ by $0$ outside of $\Omega$) and moreover $\Vert \nabla u \Vert_p \lesssim \Vert \nabla u \Vert_{p^*}$ by Holder ineq.

Summing up, it seems to me that in GNS we don't ask any condition on $u$ besides being in $W^{1,p}$ and we get an (intuitively) better bound on its $p$-norm because it "uses" lower integrability on $\nabla u$.

A related very vague question, whenever I am working in a domain, when should I be thinking about Poincare inequality and when about GNS inequality?

Comment: The main difference is the $p$. In the first inequality it is the same, in the second it is not.

Comment: GNS usually deal with whole space as domain and have $p^*$ on the left. There is also a Sobolev-Poincare which has $p^*$ on the left and on (nice) bounded domains. The proof of latter follows from GNS + existence of an extension operator (to allow use of global GNS).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro that's the whole point of the question: Poincare has a lower value of $p$ on the LHS, so on a bounded domain that's a weaker result. Why bother with Poincare then?

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli that's whe whole point of the question: since, by extension, you can apply GNS to the bounded domain setting and get a stronger result than the classical Poincare inequality, why is the latter even thought and presented as anything but an imperfect result that's sometimes good enough?

Comment: By 'moral' do you mean 'practical'? gio67's answer below is valuable.

Comment: @Aruralreader I think moral is the right choice of word here: why they are treated as different, almost independent results/concepts (e.g. by both having big names attached to them, and by hardly Amy reference even attempting to make a comparison which is more useful) rather than as doing the same thing with slightly different details.

Comment: Obviously not "moral" in the philosophical sense, but I've heard it used a lot in this sense in mathematics

Answer (score 7):

A cheap answer. Poincaré’s inequality works for all $1\le p\le\infty$ while GNS only for $p<n$. Since Sobolev spaces are used a lot in pdes and for linear pdes one of the important cases is the $L^2$ case, you have $p=2$ and $n\ge2$ so you are in the case where you cannot apply GNS.

A second cheap answer. Usually, Poincaré’s inequality is used to say that in $W^{1,p}_0$ you can use $\|\nabla u\|_p$ as an equivalent norm.
It is true that when $p<n$, you can derive it from the GNS inequality, but the proof of Poincaré’s inequality takes half a page and uses just the ftc and Holder’s inequality and not much else. The proof of GNS inequality is much more involved although it does give more information when $p<n$. So if you are just trying to say that you can take the $L^p$ norm of the gradient as an equivalent norm, using GNS is like killing a fly with a cannon.

If you had asked the difference between Poincare-Wirtinger and the GNS inequality, my answer would have been much longer. In calculus of variations we use Poincare-Wirtinger  all the time. If you have an energy of the type
$$\int_{\Omega}f(\nabla u)\, dx$$ on a bounded domain, and you want to minimize it (together with some constraints or boundary conditions), then from the energy you get a control on the derivative but not on the function. You then use some kind of Poincaré or Poincare-Wirtinger to obtain control of the function.
For example you could have a boundary condition only on a portion of the boundary. Then you could use a type of Poincaré inequality but not GNS, because to extend your function to the entire space you need the full norm and not just the norm of the gradient.

On the other hand, if you have the same energy but $\Omega$ is unbounded in every direction, then you cannot use Poincaré’s inequality. In this case GNS is one of the few tools that can help getting some kind of control on the function using what you know about the derivative. However, you can only do that if $\Omega$ is the entire space or a half space or the super graph of a nice function and if $p<n$.

But I am digressing. I hope this helps a bit.

**EDIT**
There is no moral equivalent of Poincaré inequality for $p\ge n$. When $p=n$, you have that $$\|u\|_q\le C(\|u\|_{p}+\|\nabla u\|_p)$$
for $n\le q<\infty$ while for $p>n$ you have $$\|u\|_\infty\le C(\|u\|_{p}+\|\nabla u\|_p)$$
(this is part of Morrey’s inequality). The problem is that both inequalities have the norm of $u$ on the right hand side, so you cannot use to control the norm of $u$ with the norm of the gradient.

You can combine these inequalities with either Poincaré or Poincaré Wirtinger inequalities to improve the exponent. You can put $p^*$ for $p<n$, and any $q<\infty$ for $p\ge n$. For Poincaré you need the domain bounded by two parallel hyperplanes and for Poincaré Wirtinger you need a bounded smooth domain.

Comment: Great answer. Pedagogy encourages the use of Poincare because it makes elliptic problems so easy to work with, but more sophisticted tools are needed in real applications.

Comment: Do you know anything about the optimality of the exponent in Poincare(-Wirtinger)?

Comment: Also, the "moral equivalent of" Sobolev for $p\geq n$ does exist, is called Morrey's inequality, and guarantees boundedness, which in the in the case of unbounded domain is all the integrability you could hope for.

Comment: It seems to me that the Poincare inequality on bounded domains is strictly weaker than (GN)S. Could you confirm whether the exponents in the  (1) Poincare-Wirtinger inequality for oscillations around the mean on bounded domains (2) Poincare inequality  for functions on domains bounded in only one direction, are optimal (for smooth domains even?)? For example can't at least the former be derived and improved from extension and Sobolev theorems?

Comment: I replied to the questions (see the edit in the post).

Comment: Re your edit, did you mean "there is no moral equivalent of the Sobolev inequality for $p\geq n$"?

Comment: Is your claim them that the Poincare inequality for a zero trace function on a smooth bounded domain is optimal when $p\geq n$? That is, do you claim that $\forall p\geq n\forall C>0 \forall q>p \exists f: \|f\|_{q}>C\|\nabla f\|_p$? If yes, do you have a proof of that?

Comment: I meant that you cannot deduce Poincare's inequality from the Sobolev inequality when $p\ge n$ like the case $p<n$.

Comment: No, I said the opposite. If you combine Poincare's inequality and Sobolev ($p=n$) or Morrey's inequality ($p>n$), you get $\|f\|_q\le C\|\nabla f\|_p$ for every $1\le q<\infty$ in the case of zero trace.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks

Comment: So really the Poincare inequality for bounded domains can be entirely converted to a strictly stronger statement?

Comment: Yes. It can be improved in all cases